# Difference between init() and sync.Once in golang

Tags: go, initialization

I saw two ways of using singleton pattern in Go.

1. Using `init()` functions
2. Using `sync.Once` in sync package

What's the difference, and which one is better with respect to thread safety?

If `init()` solves all problems then what is `sync.Once` used for?

Comment: init is invoked by the runtime, sync.Do is under your control; you decide if it's called, when it's called, and what it does.

Comment: Your tests can’t decide to not call `init()`; `init()` runs before any command-line processing you might do.

Comment: why this question kept on hold?

Comment: It's on hold for the reason stated: It's primariliy opinion based. "Which one is best?" is 100% subjective--this is why both methods exist. Each is best for different situations.

Comment: If you narrow your question to simply "What is the difference?" there's a chance it might be re-opened. It would at least no longer be opinion based. It would still lack research effort, though, so I suspect few people would vote to re-open it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Package `init()` functions are guaranteed by the spec to be called only once and all called from a single thread (not to say they couldn't start goroutines, but they're thread safe unless you make them multi-threaded).

The reason you'd use `sync.Once` is if you want to control if and when some code is executed. A package `init()` function will be called at application start, period. `sync.Once` allows you to do things like lazy initialization, for example creating a resource the first time it is requested (but only once, in case multiple "first" requests come in at the same time) rather than at application start; or to only initialize a resource if it is actually going to be needed.