# Singleton pattern with Go generics

Tags: go, generics

I'm trying to work out the least-bad approach for implementing a singleton for a generic variable in Golang. Using the normal `sync.Once` pattern with a global var is unworkable since generic type information is not available there (below).

This example is contrived, but in practice the code that maintains the singleton could be separate, such as in a library, from the client code that defines `T`.

Assume this library code, where the concrete value of T is not known:

```
type Cache[T any] struct{}

var (
    cacheOnce sync.Once
    cache     Cache[any] // Global singleton
)

func getOrCreateCache[T any]() Cache[T] {
    cacheOnce.Do(func() {
        typedCache := buildCache()
        cache = typedCache.(Cache[any]) // Invalid type assertion
    })
    return cache.(Cache[T]) // Invalid type assertion
}
```

And assume this separate client code, where `T` is defined as a `string`:

```
stringCache := getOrCreateCache[string]()
```

What's the best approach for accomplishing this?

Comment: Generics are a compile time specialization. The entire point of generics is to have multiple implementations automatically chosen based on type, which is going to conflict with the idea of a “singleton” if you need multiple types.

Comment: The problem of course is that the part of some code where a singleton is needed, such as in a separate library, isn't aware of the concrete value of `T`.

Comment: I'd say the last-bad approach here is to use the most common `interface{}` and drop the generics. When you write `var cache Cache[any]` that's the same as `var cache Cache[interface{}]` such that you gain nothing from having a generic type parameter. Consider defining a `type Cacheable interface {...}` instead.

Comment: @Zyl the only reason this example shows `Cache[any]` is to highlight how generics don't fit well with the normal `sync.Once` singleton pattern. I do have a need for something like a generic cache and a singleton.

Comment: The issue is that if you want to make a "generic variable" in golang, it has to be wrapped in a generic struct or generic function, which means it's instanced per function call / struct instance. It's basically impossible to create a sort of "static" (/ global) + generic variable in golang. C++ (etc) lets you define statics inside template classes. This permits generic singletons, type maps, etc. Heck, if golang functions had identity, you could map generic functions to singletons up-casted to `interface{}`. But as it stands, you might need reflection.

Comment: By the way, [here's](https://github.com/huandu/go-singleton/blob/master/singleton.go) a library that does it using reflection, as I suggested. You have to sacrifice type safety, but as you can see in the implementation, the unsafe casts / reflection are isolated within the library.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @AlexanderGuyer. That library appears to use a global type cache, which is a neat idea, but is potentially risky if you call it in different locations for the same type. This pushed me to create [my own simple library](https://github.com/jhalterman/singlet) to support generic singletons without that downside, and with proper thread safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this using the `atomic.Pointer` API, and rolled it into a simple library for others to use if they're interested: [singlet](https://github.com/jhalterman/singlet). Re-working the original post with singlet looks like this:

Example library code:

```
type Cache[T any] struct{}

var singleton = &singlet.Singleton{}

func getOrCreateCache[T any]() (Cache[T], err) {
    return singlet.GetOrDo(singleton, func() Cache[T] {
        return Cache[T]{}
    })
}
```

Client code:

```
stringCache := getOrCreateCache[string]()
```

And the [Singlet](https://github.com/jhalterman/singlet) library code that supports this:

```
var ErrTypeMismatch = errors.New("the requested type does not match the singleton type")

type Singleton struct {
    p   atomic.Pointer[any]
    mtx sync.Mutex
}

func GetOrDo[T any](singleton *Singleton, fn func() T) (result T, err error) {
    maybeResult := singleton.p.Load()
    if maybeResult == nil {
        // Lock to guard against applying fn twice
        singleton.mtx.Lock()
        defer singleton.mtx.Unlock()
        maybeResult = singleton.p.Load()

        // Double check
        if maybeResult == nil {
            result = fn()
            var resultAny any = result
            singleton.p.Store(&resultAny)
            return result, nil
        }
    }

    var ok bool
    result, ok = (*maybeResult).(T)
    if !ok {
        return *new(T), ErrTypeMismatch
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

I hope that helps anyone else who comes across this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Generics are supposed to allow parametric polymorphism at compile time, that's the entire point. So a generic singleton seems rather counter-intuitive. There's nothing "generic" in it.

If your goal is to abstract some complex initialization code — *that is reusable with different types* — into a library, you can use a memoized function. This allows the client code to choose the type parameter when the *producer* function is called.

```
// generic singleton type
type Cache[T any] struct {
    value [1024]T
}

type CacheProducer[T any] func() *Cache[T]

func NewProducer[T any]() CacheProducer[T] {
    var cache *Cache[T]
    return func() *Cache[T] {
        if cache != nil {
            fmt.Println("returning cached")
            return cache
        }
        fmt.Println("instantiating")
        cache = &Cache[T]{ /* initialize fields */ }
        return cache
    }
}
```

And then you use it by storing the *producer function* in a global variable, and ensuring there's only one using the package `init` function.

```
var getInstance CacheProducer[byte]

func init() {
    getInstance = NewProducer[byte]()
}

func main() {
    a := getInstance()
    b := getInstance()
    c := getInstance()

    fmt.Println(a == b) // true (same instance)
    fmt.Println(b == c) // true (same instance)
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/lwWR43zq5D6

You can also use `sync.Once` if initialization is supposed to occur at a later time in the program execution. The point is that you initialize the producer function instead of the type itself. This doesn't dispense you from choosing a concrete type parameter at the time you write the client code.

You may read more about the difference here: [Difference between init() and sync.Once in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953191/difference-between-init-and-sync-once-in-golang).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Unfortunately it doesn't get around the problem posed above, where the singleton stored globally doesn't know what type argument might be supplied to it elsewhere. In your example it's typed as `byte`, but in practice we wouldn't know the type at that location.

Comment: @Jonathan then initialize the producer function with a sync.Once at the point in client code where the type parameters are known. Otherwise I don’t understand your use case

Comment: @blackgreen Sure we could initialize the singleton/producer with the appropriate type where it is known, but we can't easily store that singleton as a global var because the concrete type isn't known at the global level. That's the basic problem posed by this question. I updated the question to do a better job of highlighting this dilemma.

Comment: @Jonathan storing the singleton as a *package-level* variable is not possible, unless you decide the type parameter beforehand. Generic types *must* be instantiated at each point of use. (Note that instantiation with a type parameter as `Cache[T]` is still an instantiation. I shall note that your solution also does not do this either, as it hides the global into a struct more or less like my solution hides it in a function.